# Twitter app signs out continuously

Tags: twitter

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace running CyanogenMod 7.2.0. The problem is that the Twitter app signs out randomly from time to time. Sometimes it happens in a couple of hours or in a day or so. It's annoying having to sign in almost every time I want to use it.

Is anyone having the same problem? How did you solve is?

Comment: I think the problem is caused by moving the app to the SD card. Moving it back to internal storage solved the problem. Too bad the Ace has really little internal storage space.

Comment: Confirming that moving app back to phone from SD works still in 2019.

Answer (score 5):

As [Federico Perez](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/23476/federico-perez) pointed out in his comment on the question, the problem was caused by moving the app to the SD card. I moved the app back to internal memory and it worked for me as well (so thanks to Federico for pointing out).